# Cannot install lubuntu (or any other distro) with usb on acer ES1-111-C3R9

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, bios, gpt

I'm getting crazy with this, I have installed 1 million linux distros in my life but can't with this pc. I have tried EVERYTHING, now I gonna put the list of the one million things I tried.

pc: acer aspire ES1-111-C3R9

iso: lubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

I want to use UEFI, no dual boot, no windows, just a single OS.

For every of the following try I tired with this "image setting" on the USB.
I tried with yummi and rufus, selecting GPT + UEFI no CMS.

From bios I tried with secure boot on and off, and also I tried to select EVERY one of the .efi from the bios option (Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing). I tried probably all the permutation of possibles combinations of options.

When I boot and press F12, it shows me the USB, and also all the .efi that I put there from the secure boot, every one of these just prompt me the grub 2.02 minimal shell.

Any advice? please don't answer with the same results that the first 20 pages of google gives when you search (how to install uefi linux ecc... (I installed lubuntu on somtehing like 10 different computers, but this cancer acer wont work)).

grub minimal bash output:

```
ls
(memdisk) (hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1)
```

Comment: Have you tried different USB flash drive and 19.10? However, it seems strange...

Comment: no, but I used this pen drive on other pc installation and worked fine, if i find the old pend drive I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED.
I don't know how, really I don't. I was just messing around with tons of distros on this pc, no one worked, I was able only to install a distro called lxle.

The last thing i tried was lubunt19.
I entered on the grub prompt:

```
grub> set root=(hd1,gpt2)
grub> linux /vmlinuz(the verions I chose) root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd /initrd.img(the verison I chose)
grub> boot
```

after boot it stucked as some busybox: (initramfs).

Then I shout down down, reformatted my usb (again) with lubuntu 18 (gpt, uefi), inserted and BOOM magic, pen detected immediately and start installation...
Probably black magic.

Same pc, same usb same iso same configuration, 20 times doesn't  work and at the ends works, I really would love tho know why. If someone is interested tell me what to send to you to discover this black magic.

Edit:

I remember something new I did, this time instead formatting with rufus I formatted with windows, right click on the pen and fomratted, and the wrote the iso with rufus, this is the only different thing, could this be?